# How can I generate a random number after every millisecond without closing the program in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to generate a new random every time in a `while` loop until the loop breaks when it meets the condition in the `while` loop like 10 random numbers.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please include some code.

Comment: for 0 to 9 { getRandom();} ???

Comment: more than that. But i get the value 41 more like 1041 or 3241 etc. I don.t know why.

Answer (score 0):

you could find something on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        //Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into an int in [1, 6]
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

where the `for` loop can obviously be replaced by a `while`